# Creating flag columns (Y/N) based on values from other columns from just 3 first rows

Tags: python, pandas

We have a pretty big data set regarding to mortality in the U.S. We are just using years 2010-2016 and need to replicate what has been done to create two flag columns in SAS: one for diabetes and one for hypertension, derived from the encoded values from 20 columns named ENICON1- 20, which are of dtype object but only for the first three positions or rows.

This is what was done in SAS:

```
* Create 2 flag variable to identify deaths * ;
* that had Diabetes or Hypertension as a contributing cause of death * ;
length diabetes_flag  $1 
       hypertens_flag $1 ;
* Create an array to use to check Contributing Causes of Death * ;
array ent_cond[20] enicon1 - enicon20 ;
diabetes_flag  = 'N' ;
hypertens_flag = 'N' ;
do i = 1 to 20 ;
  * Check first three positions of each "Entity_Axis_Condition_Codes" 
(1 -20) for Diabetes codes * ;
   if substr(ent_cond[i],1,3) in('E10','E11','E12','E13','E14') 
   then diabetes_flag = 'Y' ;
  * Check first three positions of each "Entity_Axis_Condition_Codes" 
(1 - 20) for Hypertension codes * ;
  if substr(ent_cond[i],1,3) in('I10','I12') then hypertens_flag = 'Y';
end ;
```

As can be seen in the code above we are looking for just partial matches of the encoded strings (as there are plenty of them), for example: 'E10', 'E11', 'E12', etc. within those columns so if the partial match is in it, then it could be translated to Y or N to the flag column.

We have tried something like this, which returns only "N", and it is not parsing only the three first rows:

```
def diabetes_flag(row):
    if row['ENICON1'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON2'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON3'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON4'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON5'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON6'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON7'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON8'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
        return 'Y'
    if row['ENICON9'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14':
```

Up to ENICON20...
    else:
        return 'N'

Then applying the function:

```
mortdata['Diabetes_Flag'] = mortdata.apply(diabetes_flag, axis = 1)
```

Which returns only 'N' because it's not looking for partial but full matches.

We have also tried (just as a test, using only one year of data):

```
m2 = mort2010

m2['CON1'] = m2['ENICON1'].str[0:3]
m2['CON2'] = m2['ENICON2'].str[0:3]
m2['CON3'] = m2['ENICON3'].str[0:3]
m2['ENICON20'] = m2.to_string(columns = ['ENICON20'])
m2['CON20'] = m2['ENICON20'].str[0:3]

m2['DIABETES_FLAG'] = "N"
Dcodes = ["E10","E11"]

m2.loc[m2['CON1'].isin(Dcodes), ['DIABETES_FLAG']] = "Y"
```

But this is eating our memory up and doesn't run on some of our computers. We know there has to be an efficient way, more pythonic way of doing it, we just don't have an idea what might be that way.

Comment: There is too much information here. Please reduce this to a [mcve] with sample/dummy data that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: you can rewrite your diabetes-flag using  `np.where` in the following fashion:  `df['flag']=np.where(df['ENICON1'] == 'E10|E11|E12|E13|E14', 'Y', 'N')`. Is this what you need?

Comment: @pythonic833, yes it is! Thanks, but how can we put it into a loop to do all of the columns at once because doing one by one could take a lot of time?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I guess I don't have any privileges to edit the post and add a sample set

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need:

```
df['flag'] ='N'
for i in range(1,21):    
    df['flag']=np.where(df['ENICON' + str(i)].isin(['E10','E11','E12','E13','E14']), 'Y', df['flag'])
```

So, this should be the appropriate code now. It's important to have `df['flag']` in the 'else' case. Otherwise you overwrite your 'Y'-flag if `df['ENICON20'].isin(['E10','E11','E12','E13','E14'])` is False!

Comment: Yes, yes! That is what we have been trying to come up with! Thanks, thanks!

Comment: No, it didn't work, it returns only 'N' and we know that there should be 'Y'

Comment: Can you provide some data samples?

Comment: yes, I do have sample data but have been trying to edit the post but don't have privileges to do so or to delete it. Will try to repost though!

Comment: wait a second. I edited my post. So if I understood correctly, you want to set the flat to 'Y' if `df['ENICONx']` is in the list `['E10','E11','E12','E13','E14']`. Right? If so, my edited code should work

Comment: @python833 Well, cannot edit or repost the same question, but I realized that the last 5 columns were only NaNs, by removing those, it worked, it provided me the 2 flag columns with Y and N! Thanks a lot!